# Answer flagged as duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I just recently started seeing flagged answers when logged in and one item for review is for a duplicate answer; [Why does Email to Salesforce think my emails are spam?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14239/why-does-email-to-salesforce-think-my-emails-are-spam/14453#14453) and [Email to salesforce error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14164/email-to-salesforce-error/14452#14452).

Yes, they are the same answer, but I was not aware that Stack Exchange flagged duplicate answers from distinct questions. I'm thinking of voting to remove the flag in this particular case but am hoping someone else can explain what's going on or the rationale behind this.

Comment: I had to skip it since I was too unsure on what to do, added what is the difference between tools and review section. The tools showed up for me very recently and I have been avoiding the tools area for a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually closed one of the questions because they seemed to be the same thing (unless I misread something, let me know!) which is why one guy had posted the same answer on each question.

I believe the system monitors identical answers just as a way to help prevent spam and the like, the idea being that because questions should be unique the chances of one answer fitting two questions perfectly should be pretty small.

Comment: To add for that: I actually waited for Op to close one of his questions, so I can merge them.